# spark 1.3 workers accepting jobs but console says resources not available

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run apache spark 1.3 on amazon EMR with hadoop 2.4 of amazon in standalone with 2 workers. But When I do I get the following message:

> [TaskSchedulerImpl] - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I am setting the following parameters:

```
conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("SVM Classifier Example");
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1024m");
conf.set("spark.cores.max", "1");
```

But when I run the same on my local (with apache hadoop 2.4 and spark 1.3) I am able to execute it in a few seconds.
I checked each worker machine has plenty of free memory around 1.6G in both cases so that is not an issue.

Here are what the logs on worker say:

```
15/03/26 20:54:27 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/03/26 20:54:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/26 20:54:29 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
15/03/26 20:54:29 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
15/03/26 20:54:29 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
15/03/26 20:54:30 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/03/26 20:54:31 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/03/26 20:54:31 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@ip-XXXX.ec2.internal:50899]
15/03/26 20:54:31 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port 50899.
15/03/26 20:54:32 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-XXXX.ec2.internal:49161] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-XXXX.ec2.internal:49161]].
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Any inputs and suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of master UI]

---

EDIT: I am not able to upload screenshot of my console.
But here are the details:

```
> Worker Id      Cores        Memory 
>  1             8 (8 Used)   1172.0 MB (1024.0 MB Used) 
>  2             8 (8 Used)   1536.0 MB (1024.0 MB Used)
>Running Applications
> ID       Cores      Memory per Node  User  State    Duration
> 1          16         1024.0 MB      root  Running   1.5h
```

Comment: How are you submitting your application to the cluster? Can you post the spark-submit command?

Comment: I am submitting it via java code like mentioned in the SVM example of spark website. Its through this line "SVMModel model = SVMWithSGD
      .train(training.rdd(), numIterations);"

Comment: If the job is lunched with local option instead of cluster, you'll have these resources problems.

Comment: On a side note, any particular reason you are not using Yarn?

Comment: Hey thanks Guys for the help.  @ ChristopherB I am considering that option but any particular pros and cons of using standalone mode vs yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns the problem was firewall in my system. The firewall policy was such that workers could communicate with master but not driver. Opened the prots for two way communication and this resolved my problem.